# Compare data against sql column

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have collection of numbers like: 11111, 12345, 12346 stored in a list in c# code. I need to compare this list against sql database column of numbers similar to this and find out if matching numbers exist. Below is what i am doing:

```
foreach (number in numbers)
{
    //get column data through sql reader and iterate through it:
    foreach(column in columnData)
    {
       if(number == column)
       {
         // do something
       }
}
```

my question is this right approach? Or is there a better way to do this? As it looks like this requires lots of processing.

Answer (score 0):

I would so something like this..

```
var matches =  columnData.Where(z=> numbers.Contains(z=>z.columnData)).ToList();

or

var matches = columnData.Select(z=> z.columnData).Intersect(numbers);
```